# Selecting Parent's Child in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I think all I need is a selector, but can't find one. I want to select the anchor tag, but can only select the `li` using `.parent()`...

jQuery:

```
$("nav ul li > ul").parent().append('<span class="arrow">&darr;</span>');
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">The Events</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Buy Tickets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The code above puts the arrow on the right `li`s, but one level to high. I need to target the `li`'s `a` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like this:

```
$("nav ul li > ul").siblings("a").append('<span class="arrow">&darr;</span>');
```

[You can find a full list of traversal functions here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: Awesome; the cleaner the better. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered myself. Using `.children("a")` I was able to select the anchor. Final code looked like:

```
$("nav ul li > ul").parent().children("a").append('<span class="arrow">&darr;</span>');
```

Comment: Use Nick Craver's example instead using `siblings()`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen on clicking the link or onload?